# Android TV: Recycler View is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-tv, ott

I showed a list of Items using Recycler View on Android TV. But my list is not scrolling and has focused on it. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
private void initRecyclerView(){
    ArrayList<String> categoryList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("categoryList"); 
    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.categoryRecyclerView);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,categoryList);
    System.out.println("investmentRecyclerView array: " + categoryList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

Comment: Can you post your XML layout?

Answer (score 1):

Set **focusable=true** for **Item's layout** :

Ex. `list_item.xml` is RecycerlView's item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
    android:focusable="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

To see if its focused or not add this sector as drawable, and add images accordingly :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:state_focused="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@color/lightblue"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: When i give,
android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
It will be stretch. Design issues.

Comment: then use 9 patch

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **VerticalGridView** and **HorizontalGridView**  from **Leanback** SDK instead of **RecyclerView**

```
<androidx.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:lb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/row_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipToPadding="false"
lb:rowHeight="wrap_content"
style="?attr/rowHorizontalGridStyle" />
```

Comment: Its scrolling but not focus-able?

Comment: I think you do something wrong or maybe it has focus but you can't see. set a background selector for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responce. This is my XML code.

```js
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countries_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="Canada" />
</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```